# open child modal on esc key press of parent modal

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have a ngx bootstrap modal and in that modal i have form. I have added the config below for the parent modal -

```
public parentModalConfig = {
    backdrop: false,
    animated : true,
    ignoreBackdropClick: false,
    keyboard: false
}
```

If i am performing some task in the parent modal(filing up the form) and esc key press i want to prevent the hide of the parent modal on esc key and show a child modal with confirmation(want to continue or exit?).

If i am not performing anything than on esc Key press want to hide the parent modal. Is it possible to disable the hide of parent modal on esc key press based on certain conditions?

Comment: Your config already disables esc right?

Comment: Yes, right now i have disabled, if i enable than first the parent modal is hiding than the child modal is showing.

Comment: I don‘t know your intention on that but I would not recommend using a modal inside a modal. It’s not a good UX.

Comment: than how can i prompt user that they are in the middle of something?

Comment: So.. just disable esc, pop another modal, and based on the click in that modal, close the underlying modal programmatically..? Is that what you need?

Comment: @MikeOne No I want to have the keyboard : true, but want to disable that based on certain conditions. Is it possible?